# AWS Lambda invocation by url => param received null?

Tags: aws-lambda

I wanted to give spring boot 3.1 + cloud functions a go, so I wrote a simple lambda:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReverseApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReverseApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public Function<String,String> reverse() {
        return (s) -> "Reversed: " +  new StringBuilder(s).reverse();
    }
}
```

Now when I deploy this to AWS and test it, it all works fine.

However, when I follow the documentation, and try to invoke it through curl:
`curl -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' functionUrl -d 'Dates'`

I see that the function receives null.

I've also tried:

`curl -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' functionUrl -d "{'Dates'}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"value": "Dates"}' functionUrl
```

or

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' functionUrl -d "Dates"
```

Comment: The former also doesn't work, and the latter is one I've tried.